# How do not refresh a page after click <a href="tel:

Tags: javascript, html

e.preventDefault() stops reloading and the calling action. So it's not working.
I want to call without page reload.

```
<a class="phone" href="tel:+11111111">+1 (1111) 111- 11</a>
```

Comment: Assuming the browser supports `tel:` links (Which basically every browser from the last 20 years does) this should work as expected. You will need to give details of the exact situation that causes this to fail for us to be able to try and help.

Answer (score 2):

Add target blank to load new window and keep current window on its state

```
<a class="phone" href="tel:+11111111" target="_blank">+1 (1111) 111- 11</a>
```